# Amount of Na+ needed to be transfered in order to depolarize the membrane?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-membrane, action-potential

I found out that the number of $Na^+$ ions that is needed to be transfered across the membrane to make it depolarized is a small number.
In what way its proved? (Goldman equation maybe?)

Comment: You mean how the exact number of ions passing the membrane is measured?

Comment: One ion is enough to depolarize it. It depends on *how much* depolarization you are looking for *and* on the areal surface you want to depolarize *and* on the exact physiological ionic composition in *and* out of the cell at that time